# Sum or mean of across gradients in weight-sharing convolutional networks (and why)?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent

Take a weight-sharing convolutional neural net, like the following:
[image]

In the forward pass, $wa_1 = wa_2$ and $wb_1 = wb_2$.  The same operation is performed on different parts of the data.

In backprop, I compute the gradient.  If $R$ is the loss function, is the proper expression for the gradient:

$$
\frac{\partial R}{\partial wa} = \displaystyle\sum_i \frac{\partial R}{\partial wa_i}
$$
or is it
$$
\frac{\partial R}{\partial wa} = E_i\left[ \frac{\partial R}{\partial wa_i}\right]
$$
??
The second seems more intuitive, but in [ESL](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/), Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman say

> The gradient of the error function *R* with respect to a shared weight
>   is the sum of the gradients of *R* with respect to each connection
>   controlled by the weights in question.

Is it really the sum and not the mean?  If so why?  The sum seems nuts -- if both nodes agree on a direction, the sum will push them perhaps too far.

Answer (score 4):

The sum comes from the fact that these gradients are essentially the result of dot products of Jacobians.

Consider the following simple example. Let $\boldsymbol{s} = (s_1, s_2)$ be the result of the 1D convolution $\boldsymbol{w} * \boldsymbol{x}$, so that $s_1 = w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2$ and $s_2 = w_1 x_2 + w_2 x_3$

$$\begin{aligned}
  \frac{\partial R}{\partial w_1} 
  & = \frac{\partial R}{\partial \boldsymbol{s}} \cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{s}}{\partial w_1} \\
  & = \begin{bmatrix}\delta_1 & \delta_2\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix} \\
  & = \sum_i \frac{\partial R}{\partial s_i} \cdot \frac{\partial s_i}{\partial w_1}
\end{aligned}$$

Note that I wrote your $\frac{\partial R}{\partial wa_{i}}$ as $\frac{\partial R}{\partial s_i} \frac{\partial s_i}{\partial w_a}$.